# StartIndex cannot be less than zero Getting Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, lastindexof

I have a button to delete the last line in a multi text box. It works so far, deletes everything in the last line just how I want. Here is the code for that

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Remove(textbox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
            }
```

but if click that button one more time after everything is deleted from the textbox, i get an error saying

StartIndex cannot be less than zero

so i did this...

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if (textbox1.Text == "")
            { }

            else 
            {
                textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Remove(textbox1.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
            }

        }
```

and it still lets me delete the last line... and the error occurs again.

ANY SUGGESTIONS?

Comment: The value of `textbox1.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine)` is -1 when you click button second time. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Empty string has an indexOf = -1 which is invalid

Comment: How do i prevent the button from doing anything if the textbox is empty?

Comment: Whether the textbox is empty or not doesn't matter. What matters is whether there's an `Environment.NewLine` in the text or not. If there is text but no `NewLine`, your test will still return -1 and generate the error.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the second attempt to find the index of the new line character returns -1, as there is no new line character anymore.

You can do  the indexOf check as its own statement and only continue with the remove if it isn't -1.

```
int index = textbox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
if(index > -1) {  
   textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Remove(index);
}
```

Alternatively, just check the length of the textbox.text before trying to do the removal.

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved. Then, you could click '✔' to mark it as the best answer so that it will help other members to find the solution quickly if they face the similar issue.